# Hyperledger Composer: command composer network start failing

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy a business network using command:

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n test-bna -V 0.0.1 -A admin -S adminpw
```

And it is failing with error:

> Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to connect to
>   any peer event hubs. It is required that at least 1 event hub has been
>   connected to receive the commit event.

On checking the composer logs, it says:

> 2018-11-08T13:30:59.190Z WARN    :HLFConnection
>   :_connectToEventHubs()     event hub localhost:7051 failed to connect:
>   12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Deliver {}$
>   2018-11-08T13:31:46.763Z WARN    :HLFConnection
>   :_connectToEventHubs()     event hub localhost:7051 failed to connect:
>   12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Deliver {}$

Could someone please help with resolving this?

Comment: What version of Composer are you using, and what version of Fabric ?  Are there any errors in the Peer log?

Comment: There are no errors in Peer log. Composer version is 0.20.4 and fabric version is hlfv1

Comment: For Composer v20.4 you need Fabric v1.2.1

Comment: Thank you. Looks like it was version mismatch. I updated the versions and now the command is successful.

Comment: I have this same issue my versions are composer v20.6 and fabric v1.2.1 But the command still does not work, any ideas?